# combine like rows

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testimoni` (
  `Source` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Date1` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `Date2` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `Date3` varchar(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `testimoni` (`Source`, `Date1`, `Date2`, `Date3`) VALUES
('ATC-112', '0h 35m', '', ''),
('ATC-112', '', '0h 34mn', ''),
('ATC-112', '', '', '0h 20'),
('BTC-113', '0h 36m', '', ''),
('BTC-113', '', '0h 34mn', ''),
('BTC-113', '', '', '0h 20'),
('CTC-114', '0h 36m', '', ''),
('CTC-114', '', '0h 34mn', ''),
('CTC-114', '', '', '0h 20');
```

I would like to have this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testimoni1` (
  `Source` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Date1` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `Date2` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `Date3` varchar(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `testimoni1` (`Source`, `Date1`, `Date2`, `Date3`) VALUES
('ATC-112', '0h 35m', '0h 34mn', '0h 20'),
('BTC-113', '0h 36m', '0h 34mn', '0h 20'),
('CTC-114', '0h 36m', '0h 34mn', '0h 20');
```

Please help me!!!!

Comment: Please update your question with what you've attempted.

Comment: it's done. New title is: Combine like rows

Comment: I updated the title to reflect your question. Update your question with the attempts you've made at getting your desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to migrate the data from the first table to the second, and all data is in the form you describe:

```
  INSERT 
    INTO testimoni1 (source, date1, date2, date3)
  SELECT source, MAX(date1), MAX(date2), MAX(date3)
    FROM testimoni
GROUP BY source
```

Comment: You should always use a column list with the `INSERT`.

Comment: @Kermit Meh, this looks like a one-off manual change. Changed it anyway.

Comment: Leads to poor habits.

Comment: @Kermit Pssh, Like storing three time values in a VARCHAR(6), a VARCHAR(80) and a VARCHAR(5) called date1, date2 and date3? Short-handing the INSERT isn't exactly priority 1!

Comment: Then comment on the poor data definition and encourage better practices. You should be leading by example.

Comment: @Kermit, It isn't necessarily a good idea to include the column list here anyway.. you are constructing a complete table from an existing one. If you miss a column from your column list and select, you'll end up with a default column in your table.. I missed the lecture where the whole programming community got told once and for all that you should always use a column list with the INSERT. Perhaps you should lead by example and add a better explanation than 'leads to poor habits' when criticising an answer.

Comment: it work fine with  INSERT 
    INTO testimoni1 (source, date1, date2, date3)
  SELECT source, MAX(date1), MAX(date2), MAX(date3)
    FROM testimoni
GROUP BY source. Thanks for your response!!

Comment: @MamadouKaramoko Happy to help, it'll work either way.. it is generally better to include the column list when INSERTing. Also I'd have a look at your datatypes; a time type might work better here than VARCHARS.